# Defining the characteristic polynomial of an endomorphism through its properties instead of a formula

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

The usual definition of the characteristic polynomial of an endomorphism $f$ of a finite dimensional $F$ vector space is $\chi_f(T)=\det(T\operatorname{id}-f)$. It's essentially just a formula. Meanwhile, the usual definition of the minimal polynomial is much more conceptual: the minimal polynomial $\mu_f$ of $f$ is the unique monic polynomial in $F[T]$ of least degree except the zero polynomial such that $\mu_f(f)=0$. (Or more abstractly the monic generator of $\ker\varphi_f$, where $\varphi_f:F[T]\to\operatorname{End}(V)$ is the evaluation homomorphism at $f$). This definition emphasizes the properties of the polynomial in question, instead of a way to calculate it.

**Question:** Is there a nice way to define the characteristic polynomial in a similar way? Bonus points if it makes the theory built on top easier (like a more straightforward proof of Cayley-Hamilton). Additional bonus points if the definition doesn't rely on the existence of an algebraic closure of $F$.

Comment: Have you looked at Axler's famous *Linear Algebra Done Right*? His whole point is to avoid determinants entirely.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have. Or rather his text *Down with Determinants*. His definition is also just a formula $\prod_i(T-\lambda_i)^{n_i}$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues in an algebraic closure and $n_i$ their algebraic multiplicities). It's actually what motivated my question, since I expected to find a more conceptual definition there.

Comment: I can't say I've taught from Axler, but I quite like the consistent approach;  the same ideas with some more advanced material are in Greub, I think the later editions split into Linear Algebra and Multilinear Algebra; I've got Linear Algebra and Axler.

Comment: Greub says a determinant function will be an alternating multilinear map on a vector space; which takes $n$ vectors, and is not identically zero. Then any determinant function is a scalar muliple of any other.  Here we go:  given a linear transformation $\phi$ and a determinant function $\Delta, $  we take  $\Delta( \phi x_1, \phi x_2, ... \phi x_n$  as a mulitple of $\Delta(  x_1,  x_2, ...  x_n \; ; \; \;$  thew ratio becomes the determinant of $\phi$

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks! Though I was looking for a definition of the characteristic polynomial, not the determinant. But it is exactly the style of definition I envisioned :)

Comment: Good. He then  is able to make a characteristic polynomial out of the determinant of $ A - xI$  where $A$ is the transformation (rather than a matrix) as is $I.$  It is Axler who really pushes:  the  collection of powers $A^j$   for $0 \leq j \leq n$  as dependent as elements of the vector space of self transformations, a sum $ a_j A^j$  becomes the zero transformation, those coefficients are transparently those of a polynomial $a_j x^j$  for varaible $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be a PID (or more generally a Dedekind domain). Let $C$ be the category of finitely generated torsion modules over $R$. Then there is a unique way $F$ to assign to every element of $C$ an ideal of $R$ such that the following identities are satisfied:

$F(R/(a))=(a)$

$F(M\oplus N)=F(M) \cdot F(N)$

This $F$ is actually a special case of a more general construction, called the 0-th [Fitting ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_ideal) denoted $\mathrm{Fitt}_0(M)$. Caley-Hamilton is a special case of the relation $\mathrm{Fitt}_0(M) \subset \mathrm{Ann}(M)$.
But we can also prove Caley-Hamilton from the characterization given above: Just use the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID and note that if $M \cong R/(a_1) \oplus \dots R/(a_n)$, then we have $F(M)=(\prod a_i)$ and $\mathrm{Ann}(M)=(\mathrm{lcm}(a_1, \dots, a_n))$. As the least common multiple divides the product, we are done.

Anyway, if we have this assignment, we can associate to each finite-dimensional $k$-vector space with an endomorphism $f$ a finitely generated torsion $k[T]$-module and to that an ideal in $k[T]$, the characteristic polynomial is then the unique monic generator of that ideal.

To elaborate on how to get a $k[T]$-module from an endomorphism of a vector space, the construction is as follows: let $V$ be a vector space and let $f$ be an endomorphism of $V$. Then we can take $V$ as an abelian group and define the $k[T]$-module structure via the formula $(\sum a_i T^i)v=\sum a_i f^i(v)$, where $f^i$ denotes $f^{i}$ applied $i$ times. This yields a $k[T]$-module and if $V$ is finite-dimensional, the module is torsion, as indicated in the comments.

Note that this construction of associating a $k[T]$ module to a finite-dimensional $k$ vector space with an endomorphism as a way of studying the endomorphism has applications beyond characteristic polynomials and Caley-Hamilton. Indeed, via the structure theorem for finitely generated modules, it provides a conceptual and algebraic way of proving existence and uniqueness of the Jordan normal form and the Frobenius, which solves the problem of classifying endomorphisms up to similarity.

Comment: But is it clear a priori that this $k[T]$-module is torsion?

Comment: Hi @Lukas!! :) ... In what sense is this remotely computable?

Comment: @Thorgott any $k[T]$-module $M$ finite-dimensional over $k$ is torsion, because $k[T]$ is infinite-dimensional, so the map giving the $k[T]$-module structure $k[T] \to \mathrm{End}_k(M)$ must have non-zero kernel as $\mathrm{End}_k(M)$ is finite-dimensional

Comment: Hi @Ted ! I agree that it's not easy to compute the characteristic polynomial from this characterization. But it's not too hard to show that the usual formula agrees with this one. It's easy to reduce to the cyclic case $K[T]/(f)$ and there the characteristic polynomial is just $f$ (assuming $f$ monic ofc), regardless of which definition you pick

Comment: Thanks already for your answer! Could you elaborate a bit on your last paragraph? What finitely generated torsion module over $k[T]$ do you mean? First I thought of $k[f]\subset\operatorname{End}(V)$. But then I noticed that this is isomorphic to $k[t]/(\mu_f)$ with the minimal polynomial $\mu_f$ of $f$, which would make $F(k[f])=(\mu_f)$, which is generated by the minimal polynomial instead of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I have added an elaboration of that point

Comment: Thank you! I will have to think a bit more about the answer as a whole, and might come back later with more questions.